# Java subtype issue: required: _$1 where type _$1 <:

Tags: java, generics

I have a class Page

```
public class Page
{
    public String pageId;
    ...
}
```

which is extended by SpecialPage

```
public class SpecialPage extends Page {
    public String specialPageId;
}
```

Now i have a class Session

```
public class Session<P extends Page> {
    public list<P> listPages;
}
```

Now when i do this,

```
Session<Page> session;
Page somePage;
...
session.listPages.add(somePage)
```

I get the error,

```
found   : Page
required: _$1 where type _$1 <: Page
```

How should i proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915751/scala-type-mismatch-required-1-where-type-1

Comment: The line `Session session;` should be giving you a warning about raw types. Don't ignore that warning, you should never use raw types.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake forgot to add that. Updated question

Comment: @moderator: Can you please delete this question. I am not getting the above error somehow on rerunning the exact code purely in java. I am trying to reproduce the error but cannot, so i thing i missed something when my code was erring and i asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the class parameter to the generic `Session` declaration so that the type `P` can be known.

```
Session<SpecialPage> session;
```

for example.